# What are 'Range' and 'Radius' queries and what is the difference between them?

Tags: redis

While searching for easy and effective tools to improve performance of Data fetching for our application, we bumped into "[Redis](https://redis.io/)".

In [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/introduction) of redis, there is following specific mention of these two types or categories of queries:

> It supports data structures such as strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets with **range** queries, bitmaps, hyperloglogs and geospatial indexes with **radius** queries...

This was first time in area of database and data structures, I have read such thing. I dug out internet to know more, but found nothing useful.

**What exactly are Range and Radius queries? What is the difference between the two?** Any explanation with example will be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Range` stands for one-dimensional distance while `radius` is standing for two-dimensional one.

Let's the data is the timestamp. It is one-dimensional and you can define part of data "in range" or `timestamp BETWEEN a AND b`. If your data represents the plane of points x:y then you can define part of them as "points closer than radius Z to the given point" or `(x-x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2 < Z^2`.

Comment: is Radius for GEO locations only?

Comment: If you can represent your type/class as cartesian plane then you can use `radius` for your purposes.

Comment: Oh okay, this means there must be some terminology for three dimensional space?

Comment: Both circle and sphere has radius that equals to the root of sum of squares of projections. So terminology is exactly the same.